# Detectar Conexion

Tags: vb.net, networking

Buenas amigos necesito ayuda estoy realizando una aplicación en .Net lo que necesito es tener una propiedad o una funcion que automaticamente cuando se conecte a intertnet el equipo donde esta la aplicacion me muestre un mensaje o algo que identifique que estoy conectado.

probe  `My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable` pero lo necesito siempre que se conecte o desconecte.

Comment: La forma de saber si estas conectado o no, es probando si tenes conexion, no hay otra.. Entonces que necesitas? hilos? timers?

Comment: si es necesario un hilo pues porfavor ayudame con el mismo o con un timer cualquiera de las 2 que me recomiendes y gracias

Comment: Es que la respuesta es esa. usa un hilo o un timer.. no se que mas decirte.. o un hilo con un timer adentro..

Comment: mira por favor [ask] y tambien [tour] asi sabes como funciona el sitio.